# Google Search Appliance: Result Encoding

Tags: utf-8, iso-8859-1, smb, google-search-appliance

I got some Problems with the Google Search Appliance, File Shares and German Special Charaters like "ä, ö, ü" in the Results page.

I did a lot of googling, and in Stackoverflow I couldn't find only one Question which wasn't answered.

We are working with Internet Explorer 8, but with Internet Explorer 10, we are facing the same Problem.

As long as there are none of those special Characters like ä,ö,ü, etc, the URL is rendered as

> a href="file://///group.server.ch/Directory/"

with Escaped Urls and works fine.
If it's a Intranet Link which starts with "**http://**", it works with those special Characters too.

For Example the word "**Ablösung**", "**ö**" is Escaped with **%C3%B6**, which is UTF-8:

- In a HTML Link, this is working (in IE shown as "**Abl%C3%B6sung**", but working)
- In a File:////-Link, it's rendered wrongly. (In IE it's shown as "**AblÂ¶sung**", not working)

If i copy and save the Result Page, edit the HTML and change the Escaped Character to ISO 8859-1, where the "**ö**" is **%F6**: "**Abl%F6sung**", it's working fine (shown as "Ablösung")
The Problem now is that I'm not able to change the Encoding to ISO 8859-1 in the Google Search Appliance.
I tried the following:

- In the XSLT there is the Part, where the "file://///"-Part of the URL is concatted:

`<xsl:when test="$protocol='nfs' or $protocol='smb'">`
`<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="concat('file://///',$temp_url)"/>`
`</xsl:when>`

- Changed "disable-output-escaping" to "no"
- Changed "file://///" to "file://"
- Set The "oe"-Param in the Search Query (which should change the Encoding of the Result) to "latin-1" or "ISO-8859-1"

All this did not change anything in the Result Encoding.

Now my questions:

- Am I doing something wrong in the Configuration?
- Are there other options to change the Encoding for File-Share-Links?
- Or was the URL already crarwled and stored in a "wrong way" (with %C3%B6..)  and I have to change something with the Crawling? (Although I couldn't find a lot of possible settings there).
- Or are there any settings in the Internet Explorer to interpret the UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1?

As there should be a lot of Users with those Latin Characters using the GSA, I cannot imagine that I'm the only one with those Problems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941052

The default frontend deals with this problem by invoking the function fixFileLinks(), which changes the link URL to Unicode string.

If you are developing your own frontend you need to run the same function to make sure the file:// links are clickable.